# Windows 10 forces Visual Studio install in German

Tags: windows-10, installation, language, visual-studio, german

I have installed an English Version of Windows 10. Everything has been working great for quite a while, but recently, everything I install is installed in German (I do live in Germany).

I want to install Visual Studio 2015 on my Machine and the Web installer forces a German install, even is I force download it from the English site. The only workaround I found was to download the Englisch ISO.

Is there ANY setting that allows me to chose that i want to continue having everything in English?

Region, Language etc.. everything is set to UK, except timezone and keyboard.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe this work : http://www.howtogeek.com/232659/how-to-change-the-display-language-in-windows-10/  Maybe it is better to change your question title and ask how to change windows language to English.Also add your windows 10 version.

Answer (score -1):

The following solution works with Google Chrome.

1. Install Browsec for the Chrome Store.
2. Use UK as the proxy location
3. Download the installer.
4. Turn internet off [if you have the offline installer].
5. Install.

OR

5. Use a VPN if you do not have the offline installer...